# What is wrong with this Web Audio API? Is it so broken or maybe I don't get something right?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Anytime I visit a website, which makes use of Web Audio API, and after that visit another one, which also uses it, the sound in the second web site freezes.

There is a message in the console:

*The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resume (or created) after a user gesture on the page.*

There are buttons on the site - play/pause/stop. I use them (I interact with the page), but this doesn't seem to work. I have to refresh the page couple of times (sometimes more than 10). WHAT'S WRONG WITH THIS API?

**How can I avoid this behaviour if I want to make use of it in a personal project?** For instance a landing page with a couple of music tracks to be played and paused. How can I be sure that the user haven't visited another site using this web audio API?

**Is there alternative of it**, if I want just to upload some tracks on my website?

Thank you in advance. I appreciate your answers.

Using: Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10

Comment: What os/browser/browser version are you experiencing this in?

Comment: wild guess that it is safari / ios

Comment: Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit),  Windows 10

Comment: if you are developing , you may experiment here -- example 3 --   https://gersonrosales.github.io/Record-Audios-and-Videos-with-getUserMedia/

there are lots of flukey results with 'resume' across browsers. especially safari on mobile

Comment: Thank you @RobertRowntree. Interesting stuff

Comment: not most relevant to refer to audio recording when u just need upload / playback. A suggestion in general is that the API, its interfaces, and the state engine behind it all is a bit complicated. Thus the non-consistent results u report

Comment: Why not just use `<audio>` tags? If all you want to do is place a few music tracks on a page, that should be all you need. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp